# how to change the actionsave to just be able to save the new record

Tags: c#, acumatica, erp

I have entry screen to manage the confirmation data, when changing the data the data will be saved as a **new record**.
is there any other solution, sorry my English is bad, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated my answer after re-reading your question.
I would override Persist. Copy the current record you want to copy, remove the updated record from the cache, then insert the new row (changing the keys as needed). See example...

```
public override void Persist()
{
    //Get your current row to copy from
    MyDAC rowCopy = PXCache<MyDAC>.CreateCopy(myGraph.MyView.Current)

    //If not saving the updated row you need to remove it from the cache
    MyView.Cache.Remove(MyView.Cache.Current);
    //  If removing more than one just do a foreach on MyView.Cache.Updated

    //Change the key fields as needed...
    rowCopy.SomeKey = someNewValue;
    //Change any other fields as needed...
    //Insert into the cache your new row
    rowCopy = myGraph.MyView.Insert(rowCopy);

    base.Persist();

    //Set copy row as current
    myGraph.MyView.Current = rowCopy;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, but I found a new problem after storing the data, the data that has been entered is not automatically displayed on the screen.
Do you have a solution so that the data that is stored and then instantly displayed on the screen. thanks

Comment: are you saying you want the screen to refresh with the "new" inserted row and not the old row? (as I am assuming your issue/question is that the graph still shows the old row)

Comment: that's what I mean, do you have a solution to that problem?
sorry my English is bad, thanks.

Comment: i updated my answer (again have not tested this) but see if setting your main view current value after persisting works

Comment: Thanks so much @Brendan